# Trouble with Reward Ads from AdMob

Tags: ios, swift

This is the part of the code associated with the error. My app builds successfully, but it crashes and I receive:

> "Thread 1: Exception: "-[(name).ViewController playVideoAd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f878ce0d470"

```
var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?
   override func loadView() {

       super.loadView()
     rewardedAd = GADRewardedAd(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
       rewardedAd?.load(GADRequest()) { error in
        if error != nil {
              // Handle ad failed to load case.
            } else {
              // Ad successfully loaded.
            }

        do {

            func playvideoad(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.rewardedAd?.isReady == true {
            self.rewardedAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self, delegate:self)
              }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `IBAction` outside of `loadView`

```
var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?
   override func loadView() {

       super.loadView()
     rewardedAd = GADRewardedAd(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
       rewardedAd?.load(GADRequest()) { error in
           if error != nil {
              // Handle ad failed to load case.
            } else {
              // Ad successfully loaded.
            } 
       }
}

@IBAction func playVideoAd(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if self.rewardedAd?.isReady == true {
     self.rewardedAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self, delegate:self)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it’s a typo? Your function is named playvideoad, while you are calling playVideoAd function.
Plus how did you initialize a function block inside another function?